# Ionic2 accessing api's from php server

Tags: angular, ionic2

Anctually I am very much new to **ionic** but I have a basic idea of **angular2**.

I would like to access an API that I have created in PHP using ionic2 and angular2.

**feed.php**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

        $db_name  = 'testdb';
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';    

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `test_merchants` WHERE 1 LIMIT 1';
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();    

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );    

        $json = json_encode( $result );
        echo $json;
```

**home.js**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  posts: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.posts = null;
         this.http.get('http://localhost/feed.php').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.posts = data.id;
        console.log(this.posts);
    });                
  }    
}
```

When I hit http://localhost/feed.php, I get:

```
[{"user_id":"136","name":"vikas Merchant","phone_number":"+6512345578","rating":"3","shop_name":"vikas shop","shop_location":"{\"lat\":1.325862,\"lng\":103.892819}","block_number":"11","postal_code":"408723","street":"Ubi Road 1","unit":"#06-48","shop_phone_number":"+651234566","shop_contact_name":"+6598765432","shop_logo":"1470280789-22431.png","shop_description":"testing shop "}]
```

When I print a console log, it simply shows `undefined`. I would expect the console log to return instead something like these data: https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/new/.json?limit=12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access the json correctly.
your json is:

```
[{"user_id":"136","name":"vikas Merchant","phone_number":"+6512345578","rating":"3","shop_name":"vikas shop","shop_location":"{\"lat\":1.325862,\"lng\":103.892819}","block_number":"11","postal_code":"408723","street":"Ubi Road 1","unit":"#06-48","shop_phone_number":"+651234566","shop_contact_name":"+6598765432","shop_logo":"1470280789-22431.png","shop_description":"testing shop "}]
```

which is an array.
You can access the first object as data[0].
if You are accessing user_id, it will be data[0].user_id

Comment: Thanks a lot @Suraj worked like a charm for me. Can you please help me by sharing some references

Comment: I dont have any links right now :) It was from experience. Will update if I find later

Comment: Hi Suraj can you please help me to figure out how can i perform post action as i did get here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better ask a new precise question in StackOverflow

Comment: Yes Suraj definitely.